# Pandas dataframe addition on selecting 2 or more columns

Tags: python, pandas

When there are 2 dataframes of same columns, how to select particular columns and add dataframes ?

dataframes in pandas are as follows

```
a_val = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3': [7, 8]}
b_val = {'col1': [1, 5, 2], 'col2': [3, 2, 4], 'col3': [7, 17, 33]}
a = pd.DataFrame(a_val)
b = pd.DataFrame(b_val)
```

How to make the resultant dataframe **C** (see below for the expected resultant **C**)

for example I have **A** dataframe as

[image: A]

**B** dataframe as

[image: B]

**C** dataframe as

[image: C]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) and then sum last column:

```
c = pd.merge(a,b, on=['col1', 'col2'], suffixes=('','_'))
      .assign(col3=lambda x: x.col3 + x.col3_).drop('col3_', 1)
```

What is same as:

```
c = pd.merge(a,b, on=['col1', 'col2'], suffixes=('','_'))
c.col3 = c.col3.add(c.col3_)
c = c.drop('col3_', 1)

print (c)
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3    14
1     2     4    41
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'assign'